# Maximum file size from S3 a Lambda can open using open() method

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently developing some lambdas to execute Python script on text files hosted on S3.

Those text files can be quite large (up to 1GB), as far as I know, Lambda has a 512Mb tmp directory, so I assume I can only load a 512MB file.

But I also read that it has up 10240MB function memory allocation.

So will I be able to open a 1GB file from S3 using the open() method?

If somebody can also give me some insights to a newbie about the difference of that tmp folder and memory ==> If the memory is 10GB why would one want to use the 512MB tmp folder?

Thanks a lot!

Have a great 2022 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object), without the need to write it to `/tmp`:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket='your-bucket',
        Key='your-key'
    )
    
    # get the content of the file as bytes 
    text_bytes = response['Body'].read()
    
    # change it to string
    text_str  = text_bytes.decode()

    # process as you want the text_str
```

Comment: So when do I need to write a a file to tmp? Never?

Comment: @pida It's use case specific. The point is that it's not needed to write to hdd to get some extra performance.